# how to fix logout api call, returning 500

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I wrote a logout api in REST but while calling it, returning 500 and url is changed to /login?logout and in response it shows index.html page

I tried return login page or simple string or tried with void method but no luck. work around, we are doing in angular

my api

```
  @CrossOrigin(maxAge=4800, allowCredentials="false")
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        logger.info("loging out the user and invalidating the session");
        try{
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(auth != null)
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(req, res, auth);
        logger.info("----user log out sucessfully----");
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Error while logout the user: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
        }
```

I tried `return "/"`  OR `return "success"`

Angular code

```
 logOut() {
    this.logoutUser().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log("logout sucessfully")
    });
    this.router.navigate(['login']); //redirect to login
  }
```

Error Code:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Reminder365API] in context with
>   path [/Reminder365] threw exception
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input  at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6b20e469; line: 1,
>   column: 0]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3829)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3774)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2899)
>     at
>   com.reminder.security.JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)

it shows error in **JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:44)**

code form JWTLoginFilter.java

```
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("attemptAuthentication(req=" + req + ", res=" + res + ") - start - entering attemptAuthentication");
        AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class); //line 44

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
    }
```

I expect api to logout and redirect to login without any error and in angular we simply call it.

Comment: Why do you have your own controller for logout? Spring Security will handle this, ditch this controller.

Comment: we want to perform some business on logout

Comment: @HiteshKumar You could add such business logic with `LogoutHandler` or `LogoutSuccessHandler`. Don't write your own controller.

Comment: @HiteshKumar However, the problem is your `JWTLoginFilter`. After logout you can't read `AccountCredentials` and your code doesn't handle this case.

Comment: Thank you dur, I used custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` and removed the controller